# time to live doesn't work on mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, ttl

see the #2443 topic
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

In mongoid, time to live (expire_after_seconds option) is supported,
but doesn't work.

I executed its sample code, then I tried to replace Time with DateTime or used Timestamps(created_at). but doesn't.

```
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :created_at, type: DateTime
  index({ created_at: 1 }, { expire_after_seconds: 3600 })
end
```

Comment: What's your mongoid version?

Comment: up to date. and I use Sinatra.

Answer (score 2):

Mongoid does not "automatically" create indexes of any kind when connecting to the class model. This is considered to be a "separate" task for which there is the following *rake* command at the bottom of the [documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/indexing.html):

```
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```

Of course if you are not using this in a "rails" config then you would look at alternate means to create the indexes on collections when you want to. You can either script this externally or directly use the mongo driver [ensureIndex](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#ensure_index-instance_method) method.

Comment: I understand that the rake command is required for rails user.

Comment: I want to use sinatra framework and db TTL function, so I shouldn't so much use Mongo Ruby Driver as Mongoid? Thank you for comments.

Comment: @Bamboo mongoid is built on the basic ruby driver. You access the native methods with the `.collection` accessor from the model, as in: `Event.collection.ensure_index`. The answer says "mongoid" does not create indexes for you when you access a model. The "rake" command is the only provision without you scripting this yourself.